# htaccess redirects that ignore query string

Tags: .htaccess

I've recently inherited a webserver whose IP previously belonged to a well known band's forums.

Problem is I'm now drowning in 404 errors!

The URLs in question look like this:

```
http://[server_ip]/forum/ucp.php?mode=register&coppa=0
http://[server_ip]/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=45330
http://[server_ip]/forum/index.php+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Result:+%ED%E5+%...
http://[server_ip]/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=44597&start=0
```

In an ideal world I would like to redirect any traffic going to /forum/ucp.php, /forum/viewtopic.php or /forum/index.php elsewhere regardless of query string.

Or anything going to /forum/.* elsewhere, if that's doable.

I've tried a number of different solutions with little success, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to redirect all traffic to `/forum/.*` to `http://mysite.com/somedirectory`, which you can replace with the actual URL you wish to redirect to, you can add the following to the .htaccess in the root directory of your sites domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#for any request starting with forum
RewriteRule ^forum/ http://mysite.com/somedirectory? [NC,L,R=302]
```

Be sure to keep the `?` if you want to remove the query string params from the original query. If you want to make it a permanent redirect, change the 302 to a 301.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know what you have tried so far but this site will probably help you.

http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/#redirects